# How to check 2 vectors for same elements, and then append non-similar elements to the end of a matrix

Tags: matlab

Using MATLAB I want to check 2 vectors, for example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] 
B = [10 9 8 7 6 11 12 13 14 15]
```

and write a matrix that checks each element `B` if it is in `A`, if it is not in `A`, then append the element to `A`. So in the end I should have a new matrix `H=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15]`. I want to check vector `A` from the end. This is the code I have right now:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]; 
B=[10 9 8 7 6 11 12 13 14 15]; 

for i=A(end:-1:1)
   for j=B(1:1:end)
      if B(j)==A(i)
         pass 
      else
         C=B(j); 
         H=[A,C];  % i want to append the new values at the end of vector A
      end 
    end 
end
```

The error I get is in the if statement: `if B(j)==A(i)` Index exceeds number of array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to find non-similar elements of `B` and concatenate them with `A`

```
H = [A B(~ismember(B,A))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that your loop variables `i` and `j` contain elements of `A` and `B`, not indices into them.

For example, these two loops produce the same output:

```
A = [5,2,1];
for i=A
   disp(i)
end
for i=1:numel(A)
   disp(A(i))
end
```

You should use `for i=numel(A):-1:1`, not `for i=A(end:-1:1)`.

---

A slightly simpler alternative to the one-liner by Sardar is this:

```
H = unique([A,B]);
```

In this case, `H` is always sorted.

Comment: You can use the 'stable' flag to get the same order

Comment: Btw what if some element in `A` appears multiple times?

Comment: @SardarUsama: You're right, then it wouldn't work. In any case, this is OP's homework exercise, they need to iterate over `A` from the end, our alternative approaches are useless to them. :)